# Rust: How to restrict type parameters for derived traits

Tags: rust, generic-programming, serde

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes a Path pointing to a csv file, parses and deserializes the file to a vector of records of a certain type and returns the vector of records.

Here is my code:

```
[dependencies]
csv = "1.1"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

First the type-specific version that compiles fine:

```
use csv;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::path::Path;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    fav_colour: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Car {
    make: String,
    year: u8,
}

fn main() {}

fn parse_csv(file_path: &Path) -> Vec<Person> {
    // Create the csv reader
    let mut csv_reader = csv::Reader::from_path(file_path).unwrap();

    // Parse the csv and collect records
    let records: Vec<Person> = csv_reader
        .deserialize()
        .map(|record: Result<Person, csv::Error>| {
            record.expect(&format!("There was a problem parsing a line"))
        })
        .collect();

    // Return records
    records
}
```

The parse_csv function works on the concrete `Person` struct.

How can I re-write this function so it accepts a generic type/struct that derives Deserialize, so that for instance it can accept either `Person` or `Car`?

Failed attempt:

```
fn parse_csv<T>(file_path: &Path) -> Vec<T> {
    // Create the csv reader
    let mut csv_reader = csv::Reader::from_path(file_path).unwrap();

    // Parse the csv and collect records
    let records: Vec<T> = csv_reader
        .deserialize()
        .map(|record: Result<T, csv::Error>| {
            record.expect(&format!("There was a problem parsing a line"))
        })
        .collect();

    // Return records
    records
}
```

produces:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'de> T: _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:26:10
   |
26 |         .map(|record: Result<T, csv::Error>| {
   |          ^^^ the trait `for<'de> _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>` is not implemented for `T`
   |
help: consider restricting this type parameter with `T: for<'de> _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>`
  --> src/main.rs:19:14
   |
19 | fn parse_csv<T>(file_path: &Path) -> Vec<T> {
   |              ^
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `_::_serde::de::DeserializeOwned` for `T`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `csv::reader::DeserializeRecordsIter<'_, std::fs::File, T>`
```

The compiler hints:

```
help: consider restricting this type parameter with `T: for<'de> _::_serde::Deserialize<'de>`
```

How do I go about doing that?
I'm relatively new to rust, and after reading the rust book's info on [`traits` and the `where` clause](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#clearer-trait-bounds-with-where-clauses) (where I suspect lies the answer), I still can't get this to compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of :

```
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;

fn parse_csv<T>(file_path: &Path) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
  /// deserialization logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works! I was trying `where T: Deserialize` with no luck. 
May be worth pointing out that DeserializeOwned can be used after `use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;` is added to the imports in the original question. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah. It needs to be imported before using it.